# Cálculo de horas úteis - Java

Tags: java, datetime, data, jodatime

Como calcular as horas úteis trabalhadas, por exemplo, na empresa se trabalha 540 minutos por dia, no sistema de ordens de serviços eu preciso computar as horas de serviço executada, neste cenário:

A ordem de serviço foi aberta em: 19/04/2017 09:00 e ela foi encerrada
no dia 20/04/2017 as 11:00, mas eu só posso computar e horas úteis em 
cima da carga horária do dia trabalhado que é os 540 minutos, alguém tem
alguma idéia de como fazer isto ?

Eu não posso simplesmente subtrair um pelo outro porque se não daria mais de 540 minutos porque a carga horária ela é de 07:30 as 17:30 então depois das 17:30 eu não posso computar.

Comment: Não seria 480 minutos diários(jornada de 8 horas x 60 minutos)? Hora de almoço não é contabilizada na jornada.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um sistema parecido com esse, vou te dar meu exemplo, talvez você consiga alguma informação que possa te ajudar, tive o mesmo problema em computar as horas em diferentes dias e acabei fazendo da seguinte forma.

A ordem de serviço é aberta sempre pela leitura de um código de barra(numero da OS), então quando o funcionario abre uma OS, ele automaticamente fecha a anterior.Existe uma tabela Funcionarios onde tenho salvo os horarios de inicio e fim de expediente de cada um, assim como seu horario de almoço com inicio e fim.

Os teste que eu tenho são os seguintes:

- Se a OS foi batida fora dos horarios de serviço ou dentro do horário de almoço, eu considero ela como inválida.
- Se a data e hora de inicio da OS é do dia anterior: fecho a OS no dia anterior no final do expediente do funcionário e crio um novo registro da hora de inicio do expediente até a hora atual com o mesmo numero da OS.

Assim ele trabalhou naquela Ordem de Serviço, até o final do expediente e retomou no inicio do expediente até a hora atual

- Se a hora de inicio da OS é antes do horario de intervalo e a data atual é após o intervalo, o procedimento é praticamente o mesmo. Encerro a OS no inicio do intervalo e crio um novo registro do final do intervalo até a hora atual.

Da mesma forma, ele trabalhou na OS até ir almoçar e retomou quando voltou até a hora atual.

---

Para concluir:

Dessa forma não somente tenho a quantidade de horas que uma OS foi trabalhada, mas tambem tenho de que horas até que horas o funcionário trabalhou nela. Assim consigo fornecer relatórios mais específicos para os líderes e gerentes das áreas.

Answer (score 1):

Das 07:30 as 17:30 são 600 minutos, então estou assumindo que é descontada uma hora de almoço, para que o total do dia seja 540 minutos.

Com isso temos outro problema, que é saber exatamente o horário de almoço para podermos descontar da contagem total. Por exemplo, se a ordem de serviço é aberta ao meio-dia, considera-se que o funcionário está em horário de almoço e só vai começar a trabalhar as 13:00? Mas e se o funcionário almoça das 11:00 ao meio-dia?

Por isso vou fazer um cálculo que **não** considera o horário de almoço, mas depois você pode adaptar o código facilmente para descontá-lo.

Primeiro definimos os horários de início e fim da jornada.
Como você usou a tag [jodatime](/questions/tagged/jodatime), vou usar a classe [`org.joda.time.LocalTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html), que define uma hora do dia:

```
LocalTime horaInicio = new LocalTime(7, 30);
LocalTime horaFim = new LocalTime(17, 30);
```

Repare que esta classe representa somente as horas, sem nenhuma relação com o dia, mês ou ano.

Depois criamos as datas de abertura e encerramento da ordem de serviço. Como precisamos da data (dia, mês e ano) e da hora, usamos a classe [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

```
// 19/04/2017 09:00
DateTime dataAbertura = new DateTime(2017, 4, 19, 9, 0);
// 20/04/2017 11:00
DateTime dataEncerramento = new DateTime(2017, 4, 20, 1, 0);
```

A seguir fazemos um *loop* começando pela data de abertura e indo até a data de encerramento, calculando o tempo decorrido em cada dia. Para acumular o tempo total, podemos usar a classe [`org.joda.time.Minutes`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html), que contabiliza uma quantidade de minutos.

```
Minutes totalMinutos = Minutes.ZERO;
DateTime dt = dataAbertura;
// enquanto dt for <= dataEncerramento (ou seja, enquanto não for > que dataEncerramento)
while (!dt.isAfter(dataEncerramento)) {
    DateTime inicioDia = dt;
    // verifica se foi aberto antes do início do dia
    if (inicioDia.toLocalTime().isBefore(horaInicio)) {
        // ajusta o inicio do dia para 07:30
        inicioDia = inicioDia.withTime(horaInicio);
    }

    // fim do dia
    DateTime fimDia = dt.withTime(horaFim);
    // verifica se o dia do encerramento é hoje (compara somente a data)
    if (fimDia.toLocalDate().equals(dataEncerramento.toLocalDate())) {
        fimDia = dataEncerramento;
    }
    // verifica se ultrapassou o fim do dia
    if (fimDia.toLocalTime().isAfter(horaFim)) {
        fimDia = fimDia.withTime(horaFim);
    }

    // calcula os minutos do dia e soma ao total
    totalMinutos = totalMinutos.plus(Minutes.minutesBetween(inicioDia, fimDia));

    // vai para o dia seguinte 07:30
    dt = dt.plusDays(1).withTime(horaInicio);
}

// pegar o total como um inteiro
int total = totalMinutos.getMinutes();
System.out.println(total);
```

Depois disso você ainda deve descontar a hora de almoço, se for o caso.